# Cannot have a dash in my database name for AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

This is most likely a bug, and appeared recently, but in the deployment section, the `Google Cloud SQL Address` section says my database name is invalid. If I remove the dash, it says it's valid.

Anyone facing this ?

[edit] My database with a dash, in the database tab of GCP console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform doesn't allow to create Cloud SQL database with dash in name, what database you are trying to connect?

[image: no dash]

Comment: well, see my edit. The database has a dash in it. Probably created from the mysql cli though. But AppMaker hasn't complained before.

Comment: Afaik, there were no AM updates for a while... It looks like validation happens on client side with regular expression, maybe it is browser-dependent?... and are you sure you was able to enter db-name with dash on that particular screen(Settings -> Deployments -> Deployment)? Does the old deployment with dash in DB name still exist? Can you add screen of it?

Comment: Wow, AppMaker interface just changed ? It's all white now. As I said, I've probaby created the database from myscl cli (i.e. `mysql -h 234....`) where there is no restriction on names I guess (at least, dashes are authorized). Not sure what screenshot you want, but I can confirm the deployment is still working (and able to make a connection to the db).

Comment: Screen of the card with published deployment, smth like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZH5w.png . So, if you was able to connect AM deployment to database with dash in the name it is definitely a bug. It would be nice, if you'll be able to reproduce it and report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192783%2B

Comment: Feel free to report a bug(you was able to bypass AM's database name validation) or a feature request(to let AM support database names with dashes and other symbols allowed by Cloud SQL) or both: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192783%2B